# I need a tick mark in material dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material

### html

```
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> M </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="element.Monday">

      <mat-option [value]="active.ID" *ngFor="let active of activeList">
        {{ active.Value }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

### ts file

```
activeList = [
    {"ID":"1","Value":"`&#10004;`"},
    {"ID":"0","Value":"X"},
    {"ID":"L","Value":"L"},
    {"ID":"UL","Value":"UL"},
    {"ID":"PL","Value":"PL"},
    {"ID":"BT","Value":"BT"},
    {"ID":"H","Value":"H"}
 ];
```

Comment: provide stackblitz or fiddle of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the tick mark like this,

```
activeList = [
    {"ID":"1","Value":"✓"},
    {"ID":"0","Value":"X"},
    {"ID":"L","Value":"L"},
    {"ID":"UL","Value":"UL"},
    {"ID":"PL","Value":"PL"},
    {"ID":"BT","Value":"BT"},
    {"ID":"H","Value":"H"}
 ];
```

Comment: instead of value i need tick mark eg: in the above question ts file Json object for the ID:1 i want to show the value tick mark

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply it helped me a lot.I want to apply the css to particular tick mark like this is below css I want to apply to tick mark--css                     
 .make-tick{
    text-align:center; font-size:100%;  color:green;

    font-weight:bold;
}

Comment: You can apply the css by using the first child attribute

Comment: just use ngClass in option, e.g. `<option [ngClass]="{'make-tick':active.ID=='1'}>`